# How to display a tree structure using ObjectListView or TreeListView

Tags: c#, tree, objectlistview

I have been looking into ObjectListView for .NET, and have tried messing with it myself.

I come from using VirtualTreeview with Delphi, so if you could point out the similarities, that would be great!

I tried creating a multilevel tree using TreeListView and the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; }
    public MyClass(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        MyClasses = new List<MyClass>();
    }
}
```

The TreeListView is a design-time component. I use this code to create dummy data and have the TreeListView display it.

```
var MyClasses = new List<MyClass>();
MyClasses.Add(new MyClass("Bob"));
MyClasses.Add(new MyClass("John"));
var myClass = new MyClass("Mike");
myClass.MyClasses.Add(new MyClass("Joe"));
MyClasses.Add(myClass);

treeListView1.SetObjects(MyClasses);
```

I also have a single column displaying the Name property.

All this works, except that I am not seeing a child-node for the Mike node. I cant seem to figure out what to do here. I looked at the documentation, but couldn't find anything helpful.

Also, can a multilevel structure like this be used with the other variants of ObjectListView, such as FastObjectListView?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally figured it out!

Apparently, the only variant of the ObjectListView suite that can be used for a tree structure by design, is the `TreeListView`!

Here is how I managed to have my TreeListView display a list of the following class:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public List<MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; }
    public MyClass(string name)
    {
        Name = name;
        MyClasses = new List<MyClass>();
    }
}
```

In the Form constructor, we need 2 delegates - one for telling the OLV that an object HAS children, and one for passing the list of children to the OLV.

```
// model is the currently queried object, we return true or false according to the amount of children we have in our MyClasses List
treeListView1.CanExpandGetter = model => ((MyClass)model).
                                              MyClasses.Count > 0;
// We return the list of MyClasses that shall be considered Children.
treeListView1.ChildrenGetter = delegate(object model)
                                       {
                                           return ((MyClass) model).
                                                   MyClasses;
                                       };

// We also need to tell OLV what objects to display as root nodes
treeListView1.SetObjects(listOfObjects);
```

I also find it necesary to refresh the parent object whenever I add children to it.

Comment: This really helped! Thanks a ton!!! Just add one more line at the end to set the objects ... `treeListView1.SetObjects(listOfObjects);`

Comment: Hi Jeff ..I want to load treelistview from xml file how should i proceed for that any idea i already posted question on stackoverflow for the same

Comment: You could load your XML file and project the nodes to a list of objects.

Answer (score 1):

I found the documentation here: http://objectlistview.sourceforge.net/html/cookbook.htm#recipeTreeListView coupled with using the demo that comes with ObjectListView pretty good.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone else having this issue, please note that setting the delegates **MUST COME BEFORE** setting the roots.  The delegates are used internally to rebuild the representation of the tree when the roots are set.